# Is there a better way to build this list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I need to generate a new list, p, based upon the contents of an existing list JRstrt. The existing list is:

```
JRstrt = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
```

The rules for creating the new list are:

- on the first pass each of the 1's in JRstrt add a sequential number to p. The sequence counter starts with 1 for the first 1, 2 for the second 1 and so on. For each 0 in JRstrt a 0 is appended to p.
- on the second pass each of the 0's in JRstrt continue to add a sequential number to the new list using the existing counter.

Here's my current code:

```
p = []
count = 1
for ind in JRstrt:
    if ind == 1:
        p.append(count)
        count += 1
    else:
        p.append(0)


for index, object in enumerate(p):
    if p[index] == 0:
        p[index] = count
        count += 1
    else:
        pass

print p
```

This approach gives me the result I need, however, I think it's a little clunky. Being a noob with Python I would like a critique of my approach. Many thanks in advance.

Expected output [1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 4, 5]

Comment: Could you please post the expected output of the example in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the same thing as your code:

```
In [42]: count = itertools.count(1)

In [43]: p = JRstrt[:]

In [44]: for i,num in enumerate(p):
   ....:     p[i] = next(count) if num==1 else num
   ....:     

In [45]: for i,num in enumerate(p):
    p[i] = next(count) if num==0 else num
   ....:     

In [46]: p
Out[46]: [1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 8, 4, 5]
```

Tiny further optimization:

Replace `p = JRstrt[:]` with `p = [next(count) if i else i for i in JRstrt]`